# Wordcloud2 package not working for figpath

Tags: r, path, word-cloud

I saw a similar post but the solution did not help.

Trying to use this [photo](https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/texas-state-png-1.png) of Texas with a word cloud. It isn't working however....

```
word_cloud <- structure(list(word = c("climate", "change", "global", "warming", 
"energy", "carbon", "u.s", "president", "emissions", "people", 
"obama", "gas", "world", "report", "power", "water", "time", 
"scientists", "study", "national"), count = c(2474L, 1655L, 944L, 
815L, 755L, 635L, 585L, 570L, 564L, 556L, 522L, 484L, 475L, 462L, 
435L, 398L, 375L, 354L, 352L, 341L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

figPath <- "tex4.png" #TODO
wordcloud2(word_cloud, figPath = figPath, size = 1.5,color='skyblue')
```

Comment: wordcloud2() takes word_freq as input. check [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud2/vignettes/wordcloud.html) for details.

Comment: @Neel I see no mention of word_freq

Comment: Oh I see, it is calculated on my end , did not include in reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, with your texas pic.(***Phew...*** It really took a lot to identify it.)

[image]

**Note**

Your code is right and it's working too. 
There is a **subtle** disclaimer from ***wordcloud2*** which you have missed is...

> **wordcloud with fig and letterCloud may disappeared in Rstudio Viewer, open into brower when you meet this bug**

So,what you need to do is:

1. run your code.
2. click on the circled icon as shown in fig below:

[image]

Comment: I tried to do as you guided but still the issue persist for me. I use windows 10. Any hint on what I can do? thank you in advance!